# How to run script automatically after specific time?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have two scripts to run backup task, one is for full backup, another one is for incremental backup. I want to run full backup at specific time every day, and run incremental backup every 10 mins after that specific time. How can I use cron job doing this one?

Comment: What time does the backup job start ? What time does the backup job finish ? Can you guarantee that it will finish at that time every day ? Can you guarantee that the incrementals will always take less than 10 minutes ?

Comment: I can not guarantee, but my script is able to deal with this problem.

Comment: I think that answers one of my questions, what about the others. Additional question: Can your script handle being called if it is already running ?

Comment: Yes, it will check the existence of previous running script, if the previous script is still running, the script will skip.

Comment: Just run your job every 10 minutes then and have it decide if it should run a full backup or an incremental.

Comment: I've configured cron job for testing, hope to see good results tomorrow